# What is the meaning of below shloka Yajurveda 25.7?

Tags: yajur-veda

I am not able to make sense of existing translations provided.
Somehow I feel it is related to virgin births where female species are able to create future progeny without any sexual activity.
Please enlighten.

पू॒षणं॑ वनि॒ष्ठुना॑न्धा॒हीन्त्स्स्थू॑लगु॒दया॑ स॒र्पान् गुदा॑भिर्वि॒ह्रुत॑ऽआ॒न्त्रैर॒पो व॒स्तिना॒ वृष॑णमा॒ण्डाभ्यां॒ वाजि॑न॒ꣳ शेपे॑न प्र॒जा रेत॑सा॒ चाषा॑न् पि॒त्तेन॑ प्रद॒रान् पा॒युना॑ कू॒श्माञ्छ॑कपि॒ण्डैः ॥७ ॥

Need commentary for understanding, not literal translations.

Comment: The whole body parts are associated with some Devi Devta. The verses are written in praising them. This is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

"Puṣan, driven by his brilliant strength, with crooked fangs, the slayer of serpents, with sharp-pointed jaws, spreading wide his feet with shining limbs, he, showering abundance, lays the seed of life and form. With his power and might, he impregnates the creatures and the world with his radiant energy."

Answer (score 1):

Two versions of the translations:

> Beg for alms from the wealthy. Catch blind serpents from large
> intestines ; serpents from the entrails and subdue them. Overpower the
> crooked serpents from the guts. Discharge water through the bladder.
> Strengthen scrotum with the testicles. Examine the strength of a horse
> from his penis. Produce progeny with semen. Digest meals with the
> force of bile, Strengthen your belly by free discharge of digested
> food through anus. Obtain the strength of administration through
> forces.

Another version is:

> Compare national health to food digestion and assimilation, blind
> serpents to large intestines, snakes to the bowels, crooked people to
> the intestines, water storages to the bladder and lower abdomen, vital
> rains and clouds to the scrotum, passion to the virile seed, food
> consumption to the bile, clearances to wind discharges, and judge the
> force of governance by the concentrations of power.

[Source](https://vedicscriptures.in/yajurveda/25/7) [Another source](https://archive.org/details/yajurvedenglishtulsiram/page/n813/mode/2up)

Comment: translation is fine but somehow I am not able to make sense out it, may be I am not that much enlightened.